# Copy keystore file to another computer

Tags: android, android-keystore

I create a keystore in a computer to export my project(using eclipse). It's ok. But when I copy it to another computer I can't use this keystore, error "Invalid keystore format".
Help me.

Comment: This is offtopic, maybe you should ask on SuperUser. To help you: How about you try different ways to "copy" the keystore? Use USB, Internet, Email, Cloud... maybe zip it before sending?

Comment: I try to copy by usb or send an email. It is not Ok.

Comment: Are the two machines running the same basic OS? Or is one Windows and the other one not Windows? Also, are both running the same version of Java?

Comment: It's ok. I try another usb and it work fine.